# How to use strtolower and str_replace to output text before hyphen

Tags: php

I like to output ONLY first and second part of before and after hyphen symbols. $interests field has values such as:

```
Eating dinner - Restaurants
Eating lunch - At home
```

Currently, it lists all values.
Here is my code:

```
$interests .= html_helper::anchor('link/' . strtolower(str_replace(" ","_",$val)), $val).", ";
```

How do I change it to output these values before hyphen?

```
Eating dinner
Eating lunch
```

How do I change it to output these values after hyphen?

```
Restaurants
At home
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp

Comment: I tried this, but it breaks echo explode(',',$val,1);